# How to find the count of occurrences of a element in an array in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

[image][image][image: test]I have an array like this

```
var arr1 = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];
```

I want the output to be like `a - 5` times
I tried like below:-

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr.indexOf(arr[i] > -1) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

But not worked,can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: specifically in your code, you need to give the `from-index` value while calling `indexOf`, for example `( arr.indexOf( arr[i], i ) > -1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr1.filter(x => x > -1).length
```

or you can use `reduce` instead (more efficient, a bit less readable).

Answer (score 0):

Using **`Loadash`**

```js
var resul = _.countBy([3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3]);
console.log(resul);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to do it by using only lops a=or something but not any third party.